# Get specific table row values by clicking a button on the respective row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
Check In             Check Out            Duration  
6/7/2013 3:24:40 PM  6/7/2013 3:26:21 PM  00:01:41:000  View button
6/7/2013 3:32:25 PM  6/7/2013 3:34:26 PM  00:02:01:000  View button
```

On Clicking the View Details button , I m getting the table values using Jquery but i cant retrieve it very time in web.
How to Efficiently get the table details on button click

My Code is

```
for (var post in result) 
{   
    $("#tablegrid > tbody").append("<tr id=subtablegrid><td>"+result[post].CheckedIn+"</td><td>"+result[post].CheckedOut+"</td><td>"+result[post].Duration+"</td><td class='mapview'><a id="+viewbtnid+','+fieldstaffid+" href='#' data-role='button' >View Details</a></td></tr>");
    viewbtnid++;
}

$(document).on('click','.mapview a',function(){

    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    var idArr=new Array();
    idArr=id.split(",");
    alert(idArr[0]+" "+idArr[1]);
    var fieldstaffid=idArr[1];

    var fromDate=$("#tablegrid tbody tr:nth-child("+idArr[0]+") td:nth-child(1)").text();
    var toDate=$("#tablegrid tbody tr:nth-child("+idArr[0]+") td:nth-child(2)").text();
    fromDateTime=fromDate.substring(0,13);
    toDateTime=toDate.substring(0,13);
    alert(" to date "+toDateTime);
    alert(fromDateTime+" "+toDateTime);

});
```

Comment: If you explain your problem with jsfiddle will help to resolve the problem quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check [Click here to see Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kfTm3/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table tr').click(function(){
     alert($(this).index() + 1 );
  });
});
```

using that you can get index of row

Comment: alert($(this).html());
its return all html of that row